# Unity Application.Quit() "quit unexpectedly" on Mac

Tags: unity, macos

I'm trying to quit our game on macOS and have found that using `Application.Quit()` will look to the operating system like the application died unexpectedly.  What is the proper way to quit a Unity application on mac?

Comment: Double checking...do you mean iOS (mobile) or macOS (computer)?  (I would expect this behaviour for iOS, but not macOS.)

Comment: I mean macOS, not iOS.  When I quit on a mac laptop, it always says application quit unexpectedly.